# How can a widget make its ancestor focused?

Tags: android, android-layout

my layout:

```
<LinearLayout>
      <FrameLayout>
            <CheckBox />
      </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I need the `linearlayout` to get focused when the checkbox is clicked, so that the `linearlayout` shows focused-background.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
checkBox.getParent().getParent().requestFocus();
```

Comment: oh, the ViewParent the getParent returns doesnt seem to have requestFocus method!

Comment: cast it to LinearLayout and use this reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#requestFocus%28int,%20android.graphics.Rect%29